# Maximum output voltage of a basic variable frequency drive circuit

Tags: motor-controller, vfd

When looking up the basic schematic of a variable frequency drive (VFD), the result is something like the following image:
[image: Basic VFD schematic]
I am aware that this is a great simplification, but in order to improve my understanding of VFD operation, I have a question about this schematic.

Suppose we have a typical European grid on the input (230 V phase voltage, ~400 V line voltage) and a motor that was designed to run directly on the grid. The 6 diode rectifier charges the capacitor up to peak line voltage of ~563 V (less under load but the exact value is not critical here). This voltage then gets used by the output stage where the transistors are controlled with PWM signals that are modulated according to a sine wave.

My question is, can such a circuit drive the motor at its nominal voltage?

My understanding is, that in order to do that, it would need to approximate a ±230 V RMS sine voltage on each of the lines, which means it would require an output voltage range of around 650 V (twice the peak voltage). Since the DC link capacitor can't get charged to such voltage it seems to me that the maximum output is a bit lower than nominal.

Note: I am aware that in an H-bridge configuration one can create an output voltage that has twice the range of the input voltage, but I think that in this case that would require 12 transistors and all 6 wires coming from the motor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe.

Since this is a "basic" diagram, there may be some things missing.  The capacitor might actually be smaller than you assume, since rectified (and mildly filtered) 3-phase gives a reasonable DC supply (~7% ripple); in fact you'd need quite large capacitors to draw the additional peak current required to follow the peak voltage, and the input power factor will be very poor (~0.4 maybe?).

It could also use PFC, which at 3-phase can be done in a few ways: one is, three single-phase modules, each from line to line, or to neutral (and neutral might be an internal floating wye point, or physically tied to outside mains neutral, give or take if the unit should support dropped phase or single phase input as well, perhaps), feeding a common DC bus by transformer isolation; another is just doing the inverse: instead of diodes, use controlled rectifiers (SCRs in early generations, but IGBTs these days), where the setpoint current of each channel of the bridge is made to track proportionally the line voltage (to a virtual or wired neutral) and proportionally to demand (so that the DC bus stays "topped up" at the nominal supply voltage, say 600-700V, over fluctuations in line and load).

Such a diagram would be a rather significant simplification of either PFC case, but I suppose it could be that, rather than meaning "we used diodes here", the whole section means "we used a 'rectifier' here"-- without saying what kind of "rectifier", just something that converts AC to DC.  That would be rather disingenuous, and at least putting it in a rectangle (implying a module of greater complexity but "this basic operation"), would have been appreciated.

Two possibilities remain:

(1) They drive at the same fundamental amplitude, by way of additional harmonics.

This sucks -- the harmonics cause torque pulsation and increased motor loss -- but would be one way to maintain nominal max torque / slip.  The waveform would basically be a clipped sine wave (plus PWM).

It could also be fully saturating as such (0/100% PWM), delivering raw supply voltage to the motor for portions of the cycle -- that is, not in regulation (a precisely flat-topped sine wave), but leaving regulation as the inverter runs completely out of dynamic range.  This is different because, now supply ripple matters, and thus how much capacitance is on it.  If it's raw 3-phase rectified (six pulse rectifier), the 7% ripple means voltage pulsates periodically, namely at the difference between mains and driven frequency.  Which for a nominal 400V 50Hz motor on 400V 50Hz mains... will be a noticeable wobble in RPM (slip under load) and/or torque

(2) They simply don't drive at full voltage, and at some point, allow voltage to stagnate, while frequency continues to rise.

Basically the nominal "100%" output frequency and voltage is somewhat less than the input (mains), and you lose maximum power rating as a result.  Kinda sucks, but maybe it's a worthwhile trade for the flexibility of the VFD (including being able to drive *much* faster, if you don't mind that torque goes to pot because -- voltage is limited, eh?), and, if you're designing a machine around such a unit, just use a slightly more powerful drive and motor than you would otherwise.  (Or don't, because you're limited on mains circuit capacity, say the machine spec will be a 15A input or something, and, if the VFD has so-and-so power factor, well, that strictly limits your power output regardless.)

(2a) Field weakening, if PMAC / synchronous.  A PM motor can be spun faster, if the voltage is forced down; this has the consequence of increased reactive power (I think?), and much less torque of course.

---

There might also be the case that, while one line may be clipping (near TDC), the others still have working range (+/-60° from BDC or 14% headroom remaining).  I haven't worked this out so I'm a bit suspicious if it actually works, but basically in the same way that the DC link common mode oscillates with respect to mains neutral (remember the rectifier pulses alternate +/-), so too the motor output common mode can oscillate with respect to DC link.  Rather than generating pure sine waves per phase WRT DC midpoint / circuit common, some common mode is added which *just* nudges each peak away from the rails, just as it is needed.  Which I believe is going to be a 3rd harmonic (and multiples thereof) (again, if it works out).

And this might be combined with (normal mode) harmonics, like the clipping I suggested earlier, but accounting for the difference between phases to maintain smooth waveforms.  Perhaps each phase's error amp measures with respect to the other two lines, rather than to circuit common?

(Three lines is *just* more than I can keep in my head at once so I'd want to sit down with some paper or a simulator to actually work this out, hence consider this section speculative.  Likely someone who's not only done that, but actually designed motor drives, can weigh in here.)

Comment: The first part of your answer is very practical and to sum it up into an answer to my question would be "no, not with such a simple circuit or without some compromises". The speculative part of your answer got me thinking though. I assumed that the common point would be at the middle of the DC supply, but if you allow it to oscillate it could help since the difference between lines is at worst equal to the peak line voltage, which is less than two times peak phase voltage. Coincidentally, with an ideal rectifier you can get peak line voltage at the DC link so (in theory) this could work.

Comment: I tried to work out what the common voltage should be. By solving some equations I got  [this image](https://i.imgur.com/qWYsURl.png), which suggests it could be anything between a sine wave and a triangle wave of 3 times the frequency. So your idea of a 3rd harmonic seems to check out.

Comment: I calculated what kind of a sine wave the common voltage should be. I got an amplitude that is 1/6 of the phase voltage amplitude centered around 1/2 of the line voltage amplitude. With this I was able to simulate a VFD that closely approximates 230 V phase voltage with only 563 V on the DC link. Of course this is still only theoretical since, as you said, the rectified voltage would be even lower in practice, but this kind of theoretical understanding is what I was after.

Comment: Good work! You might write that into your own answer -- I'd upvote it!

Comment: Thanks, I did that now.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed with a simulation, that you can't drive a motor at full power using a simple circuit like this, even in idealized conditions, if using PWM that approximates simple 50 Hz sine waves. The results of the simulation show, that the current through the coils (red, green and blue traces) is around 86.7 % of what it would be if the coils were connected directly to the grid (cyan, magenta and yellow traces). This is consistent with the fact that the peak to peak voltage of the grid is \$230 V \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot 2\$ while the (idealized) voltage of the DC link is \$230 V \cdot \sqrt{2} \cdot \sqrt{3}\$. The ratio between them is 86.6 %.
[image: Simulation with fixed common mode voltage]

Note that in the above picture, the voltage at the neutral point of the motor is more or less fixed at half the DC link voltage (it actually oscillates a lot at a high frequency due to PWM, but I put it through a low pass filter to average it out). As Tim Williams notes in the last part of [his answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/677967/maximum-output-voltage-of-a-basic-variable-frequency-drive-circuit/677989#677989), the phase voltages always have some headroom, with respect to their peak to peak range. And since the motor only "sees" the difference of phase voltages, their common mode voltage can be at any value. By allowing (or rather, forcing) the common mode voltage to oscillate up and down, it is possible to better utilize the available voltage range.

By solving some equations and inequalities, I was able to determine a region, in which the common mode voltage should be, to allow creating peak to peak line voltages (normalized to ±1) from the DC link voltage (\$\sqrt{3}\$ in normalized units).
[image: Solving the equations in Wolfram Mathematica]

The simplest waveform that fits in the region would be a sine with 3 times the base frequency and DC offset of half the DC link voltage. Solving for phase and amplitude resulted in the following signal: $$n(t)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}+\frac{1}{6}\mathrm{sin}(3t)$$

By superimposing this sine wave onto the phase voltages, I was able to simulate a VFD that closely approximates the grid voltages, without raising the DC link voltage.
[image: Simulation with an oscillating common mode voltage]
The neutral point now oscillates at 3 times the frequency, and the coil currents now closely follow the ideal grid currents.

Answer (score 1):

The solution encountered by @sasodoma of adding a sinwave of three times the frequency and one sixth the amplitude is elegant.

The normal way of solving the problem is by using space vector modulation, SVM. Infineon has written an application note describing this which also contains a microcontroller implementation. They also say that SVM can be used for "over modulation" that can give an effective 112% of DC bus phase-to-phase voltage (line voltage), although this uses a distorted sinewave that finally becomes the same waveform as so called six-step-modulation.

AP0803620 - [Space Vector Modulation & Over-modulation](https://%20https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjPidjElbCCAxWtcKQEHSV4B_sQFnoECBgQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.infineon.com%2Fdgdl%2Fap0803620_Space_Vector_Modulation.pdf%3FfileId%3Ddb3a304412b407950112b4199b7b28b3&usg=AOvVaw19uDeRsB7x7BfRL6ZHb49q&opi=89978449)

Answer (score 0):

> *My question is, can such a circuit drive the motor at its nominal
> voltage?*

Yes, the output voltage will be produced using pulse width modulation and any reasonable voltage in the range 0 volt to several hundred volts is doable.

> *My understanding is, that in order to do that, it would need to
> approximate a ±230 V RMS sine voltage on each of the lines, which
> means it would require an output voltage range of around 650 V (twice
> the peak voltage)*

Your understanding is flawed. The output can, at its peaks produce positive peaks of 325 volts and negative peaks of 325 volts easily with a DC voltage of circa 560 volts. Think about what a H-bridge does <-- it can supply the full rail in either polarity.

> *I am aware that in an H-bridge configuration one can create an output
> voltage that has twice the range of the input voltage, but I think
> that in this case that would require 12 transistors and all 6 wires
> coming from the motor.*

Well, the motor could be wound delta rather than star.

Comment: You say it can produce peaks of ±325 V, which I agree with. What bothers me is that it needs to sustain that voltage and also two other voltages for the other two lines, for many PWM cycles since the PWM frequency is much greater than the sine frequency. At some point in the sine cycle one line will need to be at around 325 V (relative to the virtual ground, which I guess is at Vdclink/2 based on symmetry) for many PWM cycles while also keeping the other two phases at their respective voltages. I can't quite wrap my head around how that can work.

Comment: The motor being delta or star should not matter since one can always do a transform and there is electrically no way to tell them apart.

Comment: U, V, W are all 120 degrees apart, and consist of (kHz) PWM pulses of either +325, 0, or -325V.  It is the average cumulation of these pulses which approximate a say, 50Hz sinewave. (Technically three of them, each shifted/delayed 120 degrees.)

Comment: @sasodoma I can only present you the facts. It would be very easy to use a simulation tool if you are familiar with them. I also don't understand why something bothers you because the PWM frequency is much greater. Ground is 0 volts and not half the DC link voltage = you are not thinking how a H-bridge reverses the voltage. I mention star/delta because you mentioned all six wires needing to be connected to 12 transistors.

Comment: @Andyaka I have in fact tried simulating a VFD in LTspice. I assumed an ideal rectifier and set the DC link voltage to peak line voltage of 563 V. I was unable to get the same current through the motor as I did when directly connecting 230V sources. This was the reason why I asked the question. Trying to find out if it could be done or not. And Tim Williams provided a way it could be done (in theory) by letting the common voltage of the motor swing up and down. Of course looking practically this is probably not how it's done, since it assumes ideal rectification.

Comment: That's how it's done